# ElasticBeanstalk - cannot pull docker image from private Docker Hub repo

Tags: docker, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, aws-codepipeline, dockerhub

I'm deploying a docker image to ElasticBeanstalk (using a CodePipeline). My `Dockerrun.aws.json` looks like this:

```
{
  "AWSEBDockerrunVersion": "1",
  "Authentication": {
    "Bucket": "mybucket",
    "Key": "docker_hub_auth.json"
  },
  "Image": {
    "Name": "repo/image:tag",
    "Update": "true"
  },
  "Ports": [
    {
      "ContainerPort": "8080"
    }
  ]
}
```

And I'm getting error from ElasticBeanstalk instance: `Failed to pull Docker image repo/image:tag: Error response from daemon: pull access denied for repo/image, repository does not exist or may require 'docker login': denied: requested access to the resource is denied. Check snapshot logs for details. (Executor::NonZeroExitStatus)`

When I ssh to the instance, I can check that the **auth file** `docker_hub_auth.json` **is being successfully downloaded**. What surprises me is, that the file is downloaded to `/root/.dockercfg` (from `03build.sh` via `download_auth.py`). Then `docker pull` is invoked. But I assume the docker expects the auth in `/root/.docker/config.json`!

When I manually do `docker login` on the instance, it adds the Docker Hub auth to the `/root/.docker/config.json` and deploy starts working. But obviously I need to make it work without the manual `docker login` in case my instance is replaced or a new instance started.

It seems like a bug to me. What can I do? Automated scripts download auth to `/root/.dockercfg` but the docker (Docker version 19.03.6-ce, build 369ce74) needs it in `/root/.docker/config.json`. Any advice how to overcome it?

**UPDATE, SOLVED**

A have moved to Amazon Linux 2 and now it works.

Comment: Hi, I am facing a similar issue, file gets correctly stored on /root/.docker/config , and checking my cloudwatch logs, the auth file from the bucket gets properly downloaded, but I don't seem to be able to find where on the Linux OS it is being stored. How did you encounter that yours was on that directory? Thanks

Comment: The `03build.sh` script downloads the auth file from S3 to `/root/.dockercfg`. Then it runs `docker pull` and then it removes the `.dockercfg`. I had ssh connection established to the instance and was doing `sudo cat /root/.dockercfg` manually each second during deploy stage in CodePipeline. At one moment the file content was printed to the console.

Comment: I saw you updated to Solved. Great news! If you could please upvote my answer I would very much appreciate it

Comment: @FaridHajnal - you are suggesting going with Amazon Linux. And you are telling that the error is happening on Amazon Linux 2. However I have exact opposite experience. Sorry, cannot upvote.

Answer (score 0):

You could use [ebextensions](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/ebextensions.html) to run *bash commands* to move the file into required place.

Depending when the files are downloaded, you can either use [Commands](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/customize-containers-ec2.html#linux-commands) or [Container commands](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/customize-containers-ec2.html#linux-container-commands) to do that. Alternatively, there are [platform hooks](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/platforms-linux-extend.html) which you can also use.

Comment: OK. The auth file is being downloaded within `/opt/elasticbeanstalk/hooks/appdeploy/pre/03build.sh` file. In the same file `docker pull` is invoked and returns error. It means I need to download the auth file to proper location before the 03build.sh runs. Where would you place it?

Answer (score 0):

I experimented a very similar issue. Some months ago I had configured an Elastic Beanstalk environment running Docker and pulling an image from a private Docker Hub repository, and this was as well implemented as a Bitbucket Pipeline.
Today I attempted to do the same exact process again for a different project and I was unable to get it running, receiving this very same error: `Failed to pull Docker image repo/image:tag: Error response from daemon: pull access denied for repo/image, repository does not exist or may require 'docker login': denied: requested access to the resource is denied.`

For my case, the solution was to terminate my environment and create a new one using the latest **Docker running on 64bit Amazon Linux** version; in my case *2.15.4*.

This auth error for docker private repos seems to be happening for **Docker running on 64bit Amazon Linux 2**, probably there's some additional configuration that needs to be set using *ebextensions* or something. Since the current version for this platform branch is *3.1.2*

However, I hope someone can also get their problem resolved by making sure to use this Docker-Linux version for your Elastic Beanstalk environment

Comment: It seems the problem is not only Amazon Linux 2 related. My environment is `Docker running on 64bit Amazon Linux/2.15.4`. I had to abandon Amazon Linux 2 due to another bug.

Comment: Got it. That was the solution for me but I hope you can find yours soon